# Sound Utility Technician

Tags: film, technician, production

I am about to do a gig  as a sound utility technician.  I was told by the production manager that I didn't need any equipment for the shoot.  Is the sound mixer going to expect me to bring any equipment? e.g. soldering kit, maglite. You know, small essentials if need be.

Answer (score 4):

I would bring your basic kit. Film sets are crazy places. Someone somewhere always forgets something. Something unexpected always breaks at exactly the wrong time. There's no shame in being over-prepared.

Answer (score 2):

Hi. No matter what I'm working on I'll always have a kit with me. I have a hard flight case on wheels that has the following inside:

- Shotgun and rycote
- Sound Devices MM1 Preamp
- Multiple cables (various lengths and connectors)
- Inline cable adapters (mainly audio but a few video bnc's etc) - these have come in very useful and gets you in the good books with the camera dept!!,
- Spare batteries (someone will always need some)
- Pair of two-way radios
- Spare headphones
- Spare torch
- Spare leatherman
- Cable ties, tape, strong string, velcro ties and strips.

That's what I'll always have with me. There are times when i've not had to open it and that made me think wether it's worth having with me all the time. But every time i've not had it with me someone asks for something that I would have had.

It's always better to be over prepared than under.

Good luck with the production.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bring the basics - gloves, spare velcro, zip ties, flashlight, multitool, headphones.  I also always have a little pack with lav mounting supplies - mole skin, athletic tape, little rubber bands, twist ties, etc.  Bring set basics as well - pen and notepad, cash, granola bars (or similar pick me ups), hand sanitizer, EAR PLUGS, sun screen, bug spray, and a hat.

If your sound mixer is anything like any of us, they are also coming stupidly over-prepared and will have plenty of anything. If you really don't feel like bringing anything, at least bring "personal" items like gloves, headphones, ear plugs - things you have to wear and maybe don't want piles of other people's sweat on them.

Finish it off with a stylish fanny pack or [this bad boy](http://www.amazon.com/Lowepro-Audio-Utility-Bag-100/dp/B0043D2L3O), a [titanium spork](http://www.thinkgeek.com/homeoffice/kitchen/8ace/) (I never leave home without one.. my wife and I have a bunch), and you are so ready!

Answer (score 1):

Always ask the mixer if it's the first time you are working with him or her, don't depend on reliable answers from the office in this type of situation. Be prepared to bring your basic kit as the others described, and above all: a notebook, a moleskin, voice recorder, whatever it takes to make notes. Mixers are particular people. You will be given notes on Comtek battery voltages, how to pack the cart, what Pelican that PZM mic is in that we will never use, but now need, what the heck did it even look like?, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!

I appreciate the feedback. I ended up not needing anything. I did bring my headphones and a soldering kit. The mixer has a whole truck worth of gear so it all worked out.